# Choose between either condition using if with logical OR in java

Tags: java

This might seems bit foolish, but it has really caught me.

I want to throw an error if a charString doesn't contain a word "Hi".

So I wrote

```
if(!charString.contains("Hi"))
   /// throw error on screen
```

Now, the requirement changed. I want to also throw an error if a `charString` does not contain "Hello".

> So, the requirement is I should not throw an error if the `charString`
>   contains **either** *Hi* or *Hello*

So I wrote:

```
if(!charString.contains("Hi") || !charString.contains("Hello"))
   /// throw error on screen
```

To my horror, I realized I am terribly wrong in writing above code. How can I write it in a single if statement then?

The requirement is:

> "If charString contains either Hi or Hello, do not throw error"

Comment: You need `&&`, not `||`.

Comment: You said it yourself: "I want to **also** throw an error...". That means you want `&&`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *very* clear way (at the expense of a superfluous block that requires a comment) is to write

```
if (charString.contains("Hi") || charString.contains("Hello")){
    // do nothing
} else {
    // throw an error
}
```

This is equivalent to the less eyebrow-raising

```
if (!(charString.contains("Hi") || charString.contains("Hello"))){
    // throw error
}
```

or (due to De Morgan's Law https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

```
if (!charString.contains("Hi") && !charString.contains("Hello"))){
    // throw error
}
```

Comment: I would prefer less eyebrow raising way

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want to throw error when it doesn't contain `Hi` AND doesn't contain `Hello`.

```
if(!charString.contains("Hi") && !charString.contains("Hello"))
```

Your previous code was:

if the String doesn't contain "Hi" or the String doesn't contain "Hello" throw error. It means that the luck of at least one of those Strings resulted in throwing the error.

Let's describe your flow in plain English:

```
IF charString contains "Hi" or "Hello" (so is a way of saying "Welcome")
    proceed
ELSE
    throw the error.
```

We can also use the negation:

```
 IF charString doesn't contain one of "Hi" or "Hello" (so is a way of saying "Welcome")
    throw the error
ELSE
    proceed.
```

In Java they would be:

```
if (charString.contains("Hi") || charString.contains("Hello")) {
    //it's good
} else {
    //it's bad
}
```

or the second case:

```
    NOT(charString contains Hi or charString contains Hello)
if (!(charString.contains("Hi") || charString.contains("Hello"))) {
    //it's bad
} else {
    //it's good
}
```